# TensorFlow InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a DNNClassifier with TensorFlow on some log data that contains a mix of categorical and numeric data. I have created feature columns to specify and bucketize/hash the data for tensorflow. When I run the code I receive the 'Unable to get element as bytes' internal error. Note: I did not want to drop the Nan values as stated in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974009/tensorflow-python-framework-errors-impl-internalerror-unable-to-get-element-fro) so I converted them to 0 using this code `train = train.fillna(0, axis=0)` so I am not sure why  I am still gettting this error. If I dropna then it works but I do not want to drop the Nan's as I feel they are needed for the model to train.

```
def create_train_input_fn(): 
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=train,
        y=train_label, 
        batch_size=32,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)

def create_test_input_fn():
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=valid,
        y=valid_label, 
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)
feature_columns = []
end_time = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('end_time', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(end_time)
device = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('device', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(device)
device_os = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('device_os', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(device_os)
device_os_version = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('device_os_version', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(device_os_version)
Latency = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Latency'), 
    boundaries=[.000000, .000010, .000100, .001000, .010000, .100000])
feature_columns.append(Latency)
Megacycles = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Megacycles'), 
    boundaries=[0, 50, 100, 200, 300])
feature_columns.append(Megacycles)
Cost = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Cost'), 
    boundaries=[0.000001e-08, 1.000000e-08, 5.000000e-08, 10.000000e-08, 15.000000e-08 ])
feature_columns.append(Cost)
device_brand = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('device_brand', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(device_brand)
device_family = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('device_family', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(device_family)
browser_version = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('browser_version', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(browser_version)
app = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('app', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(app)
ua_parse = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('ua_parse', 1000), 10)
feature_columns.append(ua_parse)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[256, 128, 64], 
                                       feature_columns=feature_columns, 
                                       n_classes=2, 
                                       model_dir='graphs/dnn')

train_input_fn = create_train_input_fn()
estimator.train(train_input_fn, steps=2000)
```

Then I receive this error:

```
InternalErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-6abd6f1afc3a> in <module>()
      1 train_input_fn = create_train_input_fn()
----> 2 estimator.train(train_input_fn, steps=2000)

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    312 
    313     saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 314     loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    315     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    316     return self

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    813         loss = None
    814         while not mon_sess.should_stop():
--> 815           _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
    816       return loss
    817 

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.pyc in __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback)
    649     if exception_type in [errors.OutOfRangeError, StopIteration]:
    650       exception_type = None
--> 651     self._close_internal(exception_type)
    652     # __exit__ should return True to suppress an exception.
    653     return exception_type is None

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.pyc in _close_internal(self, exception_type)
    686         if self._sess is None:
    687           raise RuntimeError('Session is already closed.')
--> 688         self._sess.close()
    689       finally:
    690         self._sess = None

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.pyc in close(self)
    932     if self._sess:
    933       try:
--> 934         self._sess.close()
    935       except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS:
    936         pass

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.pyc in close(self)
   1076       self._coord.join(
   1077           stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_period_secs,
-> 1078           ignore_live_threads=True)
   1079     finally:
   1080       try:

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.pyc in join(self, threads, stop_grace_period_secs, ignore_live_threads)
    385       self._registered_threads = set()
    386       if self._exc_info_to_raise:
--> 387         six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
    388       elif stragglers:
    389         if ignore_live_threads:

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_queue_runner.pyc in _run(self, sess, enqueue_op, feed_fn, coord)
     92         try:
     93           feed_dict = None if feed_fn is None else feed_fn()
---> 94           sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
     95         except (errors.OutOfRangeError, errors.CancelledError):
     96           # This exception indicates that a queue was closed.

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1127       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1128                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1129     else:
   1130       results = []

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1342     if handle is None:
   1343       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1344                            options, run_metadata)
   1345     else:
   1346       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1361         except KeyError:
   1362           pass
-> 1363       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1364 
   1365   def _extend_graph(self):

InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes.
```

Comment: i am also getting the same error.

did u get any solution?

Comment: @maswadkar I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974009/tensorflow-python-framework-errors-impl-internalerror-unable-to-get-element-fro) which progressed me further but I eventually moved to this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive) which helped more but meant I need to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof. 
You saved my day !!

Comment: @maswadkar You are very welcome. Just glad I could help.

Comment: Most the time, this means train_label is not numeric, can you print what is it?

Comment: @Prof.Falken What was the problem? I have a similar problem not during training time though, in serving time. I've read all similar questions in stack overflow but still haven't been able to solve it

Comment: @danielZapata The issue was that the data being feed into tensorflow was a mix of data (categorical and quantitative). TF needs quantitative values and so any categorical values will need to be represented as numbers. So the NaN or nulls needed to be weight numerically. Changing label types as SvGA needs suggests would work but in my situation it was easier to go back and clean the data to separate the column into two (categorical and quantitative).Sorry if this does not solve the error but I have since incorporated better ETL processes to avoid TF errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas Decaux. I experienced exactly the same issue. I checked that my labels were represented as strings ("yes" and "no) rather than integers (1,0). After converting labels to int64 no such errors appeared.